# calling image and text from database

Tags: android, database

I am finding it really hard to describe what am looking for.Iv not made a database yet.But what am looking to do is make a database that will call activists or screen shot of information on what the users looking for.The more I read about android the more I want to learn but just can't seem to get my head round DB.

My plan is to have a listview and when the user clicks there car model lets say the listview will disappear and this new page of information with appear for them to read that's all.

My Question is which is the best way to build a database with what i have in mind
I know newbies get a lot on stick on here what with not making clear what they are asking 
hope i did thanks.

Comment: The problem isn't so much not making it clear but not having a precise question. Something like this is better for programmers.stackexchange.com. Draw up what you want on a whiteboard or paper, get an idea of how you want it to operate, then start on the code and when you get stuck post a specific, code related, question on here with relevant code and any error/logcat messages. Good luck to you!

Comment: codeMagic Thank you for your reply i will start that now.

Comment: You're welcome. If you are just learning Android then I would suggest not worrying about the DB just yet and learn Android then learn to incorporate a DB into it. Its good to think ahead and make it customizable but you still need to take it one step at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to be more clear with your needs...from what i understood you'll need to launch an activity when an item is clicked. To get the information like text and description of the car move the cursor of the database to the position clicked. From there you can get all the data from your db and put in the intent for the next activity. Then in your next activity retrieve data from the intent.

If this is what you want then I can give you some links else please come up with a more clear description.

EDIT: Flow would be like this

1. Use SimpleCursorAdapter to populate your listview from database.

If you don't know how to create database use this [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android) codeproject. And [this](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/) is how you will use simplecursoradapter but instead you will use you own cursor to query the db. Like:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from tbl_name",SelectionArgs[]);
```

1. Then you'll use setOnItemClickListener on ListView

   listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       cursor.moveToPosition(position);
       String something = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("something"));
       String somethingelse = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("somethingelse"));
       Intent nextActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
       nextActivity.put("Key",Value);//place your appropriate strings in value with different keys
       MainActivity.this.startActivity(nextActivity);
   }
   });
2. Then in next activity retrieve those strings like:

   Intent mintent = getIntent();
   String something = mintent.getString("Key");//here put the keys you assigned in last activity.And eventually set your layout Views...

Comment: Thank you so much i will start loook into this.